# Used defined cell in reference to range

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the formatting from worksheet "Info!B1:B23" to "Data!B2:??23".  The row numbers are always 1 - 23.  The column will always starts in column B but the number of columns in the destination worksheet can change.

This is what I have so far, but can't figure out how to use my column count in the code to paste the formatting.

```
Sub FormatPlans()
    '
    ' FormatPlan Macro
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Data")
    colLast = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Sheets("Info").Range("B1:B23").Copy
    With ws.Range("B1,colLast")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `ws.Range("B1",ws.Cells(23,colLast))`

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much.  Works perfect!!